# want avg point for one team from 2 separate columns in ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, average

GAME table:

```
GAME_ID - NUMBER    
GAME_DATE - DATE
ARENA - VARCHAR2(20)
HOME - VARCHAR2(30)
AWAY - VARCHAR2(30)
"HOME POINT" - NUMBER
"AWAY POINT" - NUMBER
```

HOME and AWAY identify the team name. "HOME POINT" and "AWAY POINT" are corresponding to these columns. For example(just expressed in 4 columns), I want to get average point for one team. Considering example below, I want to get AVG point for AAA, BBB, CCC and DDD team.

```
AAA
BBB
90 <- got by AAA
100 <- got by BBB
------------------------
AAA
CCC
99 <- got by AAA
82 <- got by CCC
------------------------
AAA 
DDD
100 <- got by AAA
78 <- got by CCC
```

I tried code below but it did not make ideal result:

```
SELECT HOME, SUM("HOME POINT") + SUM("AWAY POINT") / COUNT(*)
FROM GAME 
GROUP BY HOME
```

Answer (score 1):

Unpivot the data and aggregate  One method uses `union all`:

```
select team, avg(points)
from ((select home as team, home_points as points from games) union all
      (select away as team, away_points as points from games)
     ) t
group by team;
```

In Oracle 12C+, I would recommend a lateral join rather than `union all`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it with a lateral join; this syntax is available in Oracle since version 12c, and in this situation it is more efficient than `union all`, since it does not require scanning the table twice:

```
select t.team, avg(t.points) avg_points
from games g
cross apply (
    select home team, home_points points from dual
    union all select away, away_points points from dual
) t
group by t.team
```

Side notes:

- I would recommend storing the points as `int` rather than numbers (presumably, points don't have a decimal part)
- use column names that do not require quoting (`home_points` is better than `"home point"`)

This **[demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ed427352d02c9ec2da04d9d8999ede85)** with your sample data yields:

```
TEAM | AVG_POINTS
:--- | ---------:
AAA  |      96.33
BBB  |        100
CCC  |         82
DDD  |         78
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with points as (
select home as team, sum("HOME POINT") as point_sum,
count("HOME POINT") as point_qty
from game 
group by home
having count("HOME POINT")!=0

union all

select away as team, sum("AWAY POINT") as point_sum,
count("AWAY POINT") as point_qty
from game 
group by away
having count("AWAY POINT")!=0
)

select team, sum(point_sum)/sum(point_qty) as avg_point
from points
group by team;
```